# Certain commands not working for a user with sudo after adding to `sudoers` file

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions, sudo, visudo

I cannot seem to allow the user (In this case Ruby) to run `sudo rm -rf`, `sudo rmdir`, or `sudo mkdir`. I have tried it with other commands and it works fine allowing that user to run `sudo apt-get update` it just does not work allowing them to do those commands.

Here is my sudoers file if this helps:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset,pwfeedback
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
Ruby    ALL=/usr/bin/apt-get update,/usr/bin/rm,/usr/bin/rmdir,/usr/bin/mkdir

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain `rm`, `rmdir`, `mkdir` are in `/bin`, not `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong path to `rm`, `rmdir` and `mkdir` commands. Change your line to this instead:

```
Ruby ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get update, /bin/rmdir, /bin/rm, /bin/mkdir
```

Answer (score 2):

When editing the sudoers file you need to [**use `visudo`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Editing_the_sudoers_file) rather than editing the file manually to actually use the resulting configuration immediately.

Also, are you sure the username is really "Ruby" with a capital "r"? It's accepted best practice to use all lower case characters in *nix user names.

Comment: Yes I know it is not the best practice to use a capital letter for username but I just like it more.